# can't find the right architecture for my crowdfunding cordapp

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am a computer science engineering student. I am working on a crowdfunding cordapp, but I still have some confusions :

1. I want to know if Corda is the most suitable protocol to use in a crowdfunding app or if there is better solutions ?
2. Is it logical that every person who wants to contribute in a project or to add a project on the platform is mandatory to run a corda network and have his own node ?
3. If it's not how could i handle the users accounts and their transactions ??
4. The next point is that I can’t figure out the right architecture of the app.

If anyone can clarify these points I would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about Corda, but I made the crowdfunding app using Truffle framework. [Truffle](https://truffleframework.com/) is one of the best framework for developing Smart Contract and Distributted application. The framework allows you to run in memory blockchain too for the testing.

Regarding the Crowdfunding app I created all the business logic in the Smart Contract and handle the authentication through the meta mask plugin. The user has to have metamask which ease the transaction too. So every transaction which add the data in blockchain goes through the MetaMask. Whereas I store the etherum address of the user in the array and relevant data in the structure.

For the frontend part I used the angularJs to create the Distributted application. The app interact with Web3 library to communicate with the Blockchain. You can also find the angular box as a starting point from [here](https://truffleframework.com/boxes/angular-truffle-box)

Comment: that's possible in ethereum because of the use of wallet but i think that this do not exist in corda i can't handle different account using one node